# Faster startup of zsh

Tags: zsh, performance, profiling

I love tmux, but whenever I need to create a split with a new pane or a new window it has to run my zsh init scrips and `.profile`, etc. And they take about a few seconds to run. *Initializing stuff like [fasd](https://github.com/clvv/fasd) etc.*

Is it possible to make it faster to start?

Comment: Something appears wrong, a new shell should be pretty much instantaneous.  The usual way to arrange things is to have things which take a long time happen in .profile and only run `.zshrc` in new shells. Is it only `fasd` which is slowing your startup? At the moment your question is very broad so it is hard to help.

Comment: Going by your description, zsh's startup time is the issue, not something related to tmux.

Comment: Uninstall Oh-My-Zsh...

Comment: `fasd` pronounced fast, if it isn't and you don't need it make sure you put don't execute in your `.profile` depending on $TMUX being set

Answer (score 7):

“Initializing stuff like fasd etc.” — well, doing complex things is bound to take some time.

Here are a few generic tips to speed up zsh startup:

- Only run commands you actually need. Don't use huge generic frameworks like oh-my-zsh that define yet another configuration layer that pretends to cater for everyone (but actually doesn't, anyway).
- Avoid running subprocesses. For short string manipulation, use zsh's built-in constructs, not `cut`, `sed`, `awk`, etc.
- Use byte-compiled files for anything large.
- Make sure that completion information is cached: pass `-d` to `compinit`.
- Load things lazily, i.e. on first use. Use `autoload` liberally.

To find what's taking so long, profile your `.zshrc`.

- You can get some measurements from the zsh profiler. Add `zmodload zsh/zprof` at the top of your `.zshrc` and run `zprof`.
- You can trace what zsh is doing (note that the tracing itself will slow things down, but in a mostly-uniform manner). Add `setopt prompt_subst; zmodload zsh/datetime; PS4='+[$EPOCHREALTIME]%N:%i> '; set -x` at the top of your `.zshrc`.